# Symfony2: instantiating form event subscribers in service container

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I am trying to associate a custom Event Subscriber to all the forms of my application.

I started by creating the Event Subscriber class

```
    <?php

    namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

    use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;

    /**
    * Custom form listener.
    */
    class FormListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
    {

        public static function getSubscribedEvents()
        {
            return array(
                FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT      => 'onPreSubmit',
                FormEvents::SUBMIT          => 'onSubmit',
                FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT     => 'onPostSubmit',
                FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA    => 'onPreSetData',
                FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA   => 'onPostSetData',
            );
        }

        public function onPreSubmit(FormEvent $event)
        {
            // code here
        }

        public function onSubmit(FormEvent $event)
        {
            // code here
        }

        public function onPostSubmit(FormEvent $event)
        {
            // code here
        }

        public function onPreSetData(FormEvent $event)
        {
            // code here
        }

        public function onPostSetData(FormEvent $event)
        {
            // code here
        }

    }
```

I know I can associate it to a form inside its `buildForm` function

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        // code here

        ->addEventSubscriber(new \AppBundle\EventListener\FormListener());
    }
```

and everything works fine so far.

Now is the question: since I would like to add this event substriber to all the forms of my application (to perform some common checks and provide hooks for form manipulation) I thought not to instantiate my event subscriber inside each form, but inside the service container (in services.yml) like this:

```
    appbundle.form.listener:
        class: AppBundle\EventListener\FormListener
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

Needless to say, this second approach is not working. So my question is: am I doing something wrong? Is it possible to listen to form events ***outside*** the form? Is there something wrong with my approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create form extension for FormType, which is base type for all other.

Form extension should look like this:

```
namespace AppBundle\Form\Extension;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractTypeExtension;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FormType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class FormTypeExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder->addEventSubscriber(new \AppBundle\EventListener\FormListener());
    }

    public function getExtendedType()
    {
        return FormType::class;
    }
}
```

Then register this extension in service container like this:

```
services:
    app.form_type_extension:
        class: AppBundle\Form\Extension\FormTypeExtension
        tags:
            - { name: form.type_extension, extended_type: Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FromType }
```

Further reference in [the cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_form_type_extension.html)